# Android ConstraintLayouts are inconsistent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

In Android Studio I design a new `Activity` UI to look like the following:

[image]

But at runtime all the widgets (except the **Min (sec)** `TextView`) are piled on top of each other in the top-left cornern (I'd include a screenshot but Imgur or AWS S3 are having problems and SO won't allow me to upload it).

Here's the UI XML that I currently have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.zacharvey.freedomawsapp.MatchSetupActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:text="Match Setup"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Consent Type:"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="64dp"
        layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/consent.voice"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"
        android:text="Voice-Activated"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="95dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="202dp"
        layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/consent.switch"
        android:layout_width="201dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:text="Connected Switches"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="126dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/consent.voice" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Go Offset:"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="196dp"
        layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/consent.switch" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Min (sec):"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Max (sec):"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="290dp"
        layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/offset.min"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="233dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="107dp"
        layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/offset.max"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="4"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="290dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="108dp"
        layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/offset.min" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toO1Login"
        android:text="Next >>"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="398dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/offset.max" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My question: Why is my **Min (sec)** `TextView` the only widget displaying in the correct position? What do I need to do to the other widgets/views to make them position correctly as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views are not constrainted vertically. You should use some type of `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` and such at some point.

Your "Min (Sec)" view is the only one displayed correctly because it is the only one constrainted vertically. Change your code to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"                                             
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="27dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Match Setup"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Consent Type:"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/consent.voice"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="202dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="false"
        android:text="Voice-Activated"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/consent.switch"
        android:layout_width="201dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Connected Switches"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/consent.voice"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Go Offset:"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/consent.switch"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Min (sec):"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Max (sec):"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/offset.min"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:ems="10"

        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView8"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/offset.max"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/textView9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/offset.min"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView9"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:onClick="toO1Login"
        android:text="Next >>"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin (+1) - ok let me ask this another way, let's say that I want all of my views/widgets to just be left-aligned and stacked on top of one another, yielding a sort of "vertical ordering" where the "first" view appears in the top-left corner, the "2nd" view appears directly underneath that (but again, left-aligned), etc...What XML attribute(s) would I need to add to each view to accomplish this? Thanks again so much!

Comment: use `layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"` on every view, use `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` on your top most view and `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="id_of_the_previous_view"` for the rest.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin (+1 again) but please see my update above. I added in your latest changes and still all views/widgets are getting stacked (z-axis) on top of one another in the top-left corner of the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: @smeeb See my updated answer. Please, read the code carefully to make sure you understand how the `ConstraintLayout` works.